# HttpRequest setentity alternative

Tags: apex, httprequest

I am trying to implement send a request to an external URL. 
External URL: https://testWeb.xxx.com
This is a sample Java implementation of this:

```
   HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url.toString());
            post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML.toString());
            post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(RequestGenerator.login(userName, password).getBytes("UTF-8")));
            HttpResponse response = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(post);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

The corresponding Apex code is:

```
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
String xmlRequest = ReqGenerator.login(userName, password);    
req.setBody(xmlRequest);
res = http.send(req);                
Integer statusCode = res.getStatusCode();
```

I get a response from a server that is quite different from the Java's version.

```
<authResp token="adfafaf" username="adfafd"/>
```

Apex's version response:

```
<authResp />
```

It seems that something is wrong with the request in Apex. What I seem to miss is the setEntity() method's alternative in Apex. Is this what I'm missing?

Comment: Does that add parameters? Headers? Both? Neither?

Comment: setEntity does set the requestXML in bytes. [Java Doc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest.html?is-external=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the header to `'Application/xml'`. I have read that the header values are case insensitive too. Guess that this is due to incorrect implementation at the server side.

The answer for Java's alternative to `HttpPost.setEntity(Bytes)` alternative is `HttpRequest.setBody(String)`. It did not cause any issue. Another way is to use other setBody alternatives such as `HttpRequest.setBodyAsBlob(Blob.valueOf(String))` or `HttpRequest.setBodyDocument(Dom.Document))`.

Comment: So you have solved the problem right?

Comment: Yes. It is solved.

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen in the past is something like below:

```
final String HEADER_TOKEN = 'Authorization';
String token = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(
    Blob.valueOf(callout.Username__c + ':' + callout.Password__c)
);
request.setHeader(HEADER_TOKEN, token);
```

Comment: This is what I do after logging in. Currently, the login request requires sending xml and then getting response.